# Programmatically created a button on iOS, but no action when pressed

Tags: ios, uibutton

I created a button just like the code below, but it will not respond in the log (supposed to show "ha"). The strangest part is that I have been able to get this exact code to work inside a collection view, but not normally on a viewcontroller. What am I doing wrong with the button press "myAction"?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *buttonz = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonz.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 30);
        [buttonz setTitle:@"Charge" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonz addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonz setEnabled:YES];

        [buttonz setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        //add the button to the view
        [backImageView addSubview:buttonz];
}

-(void)myAction:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"ha");
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"ha");
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to add [super viewDidLoad]; in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)

You don't need to "`resignFirstResponder`" on a button (seems like most of the time I see "`resignFirstResponder`" is in text fields or text views).

2)

Change the control event from UIControlEventTouchUpInside to UIControlEventTouchDown

3)

The parent UIImageView might not have "`userInteractionEnabled`" set to true, which means events won't be propogated (or sent along) to subviews.

To make those events available to subviews, change the parent view's userInteractionEnabled property via:

```
backImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

before adding that subview.

Comment: It was the 3rd one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default image `userInteractionEnabled` is disable. So, you have to enable it by `backImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`